# subitem of a listview not showing in arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am looking for a list/gridView where each item looks like:

```
|-----|   |--------------------------|
| H1  |   |   Short Desc1            |
|-----|   |--------------------------|    //Preferred View
|------------------------------------|
|    Long Description                |
|------------------------------------|
```

or like:

```
|------| |------------------------------|
|      | |   Short Desc1                |
|  H1  | |------------------------------|
|      |                                  //Optional View
|      | |------------------------------|
|------| |______Long Description________|
```

To start with, i have started with the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

which in design view of android studio, shows acceptable output as:
[image: this, with item and subitem]
But, with this java code:

```
public class FourthFragment extends ListFragment {

    String names[] ={"A", "B", "C", "D"};

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fourth, container, false);
//        TextView tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//        tv.setText("My Header");

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));
        return myFragmentView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // on click display the item in toast
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (String)l.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    static FourthFragment newInstance(int num) {
        FourthFragment fourthFragment = new FourthFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        fourthFragment.setArguments(args);

        return fourthFragment;
    }

}
```

its only showing the menu, without any submenu, as:
[image]

With The First Picture as preferred, how I can get the output?
Or, simply, what's I am missing in my code?

I am calling this function from a `pagerAdapter` as:

```
        case 1:
            return FourthFragment.newInstance(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to create your own Adapter using by extending BaseAdapter. The One which you have used is an ArrayAdapter and the layout is the predefined layout of android mentioned here**
 `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));`

Take this example[image: One tiem looks like]

So your XML layout of that item would be as below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

    <!-- Rightend Duration -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

     <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Until now we completed designing part of the list view. Create a new class  Adapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap&lt;String, String&gt; song = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

In Your Activity:

```
// All static variables
static final String URL = "https://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt; songsList = new ArrayList&lt;HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;&gt;();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
    for (int I = 0; I &lt; nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap&lt;String, String&gt; map = new HashMap&lt;String, String&gt;();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}}
```